# How to retrieve a subsubchild using XPath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm testing an XML structure:

```
<Articles>


...


   <Article ID="333">

     <author>Paul</author>

     <title>i hate xpath </title>

        <child1>bla</child1>

       <child2>blabla
          <subchild>
             <subsubchild DEEP = "Attribute"></subsubchild>     //this is my nightmare
          </subchild>
       </child2>

       <child3>testing</child3>

   </Article> 
...

</Articles>
```

What XPath expression will fetch and update the `subsubchild` attrib value? I am mostly concerned with fetching and updating sub values of any node, no matter how deeply or superficially located, if the parent ID (333 in this case) is known.

Currently I have used :

```
$query= "//*[@ID=333]//*node()[@DEEP and @DEEP = "Attribute"]";
$outcome = $xml->xpath($query);
    echo isset($outcome[0][0]) ? "found" : "unavailable";
```

and several more related expressions, they're all frustrating my efforts with Invalid expression report.

```html
function XMLChangeAttribValue($ParentID, $attirbName, $attribValue, $NewValue){
        
            $xml    //Never mind, i've create this sucessfully 

 
            $query = "//*[@ID=$ParentID]//*[@$attirbName = $attribValue]";
                    

            $outcome = $xml->xpath($query);
            echo isset($outcome[0][0]) ? "found" : "unavailable";
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question is. By "Invalid expression report" do you mean that the XPath engine reports an error? Then, please show it. Are you using PHP? Then, tag the question as such. XPath is not the right tool to _update_ an XML document, please show your expected output as XML.

Comment: Refrain from personal remarks - they do not exactly help getting a good answer for your question. Addressing my comments would help, though.

Comment: am sorry Mathias if i sounded imodest, i didnt mean to, i's only supprised at ur saying xpath cannot be used (or rather is not the right tool) for updating xml. what could be better ? a foreach loop ? well by update i meant that i wanna change the value of the DEEP (Attribute) to something of my choice. if u have idea, pls tell me. once more, accept my appology.

Comment: To someone who knows XPath, it does not come as a surprise really. Again, and for the last time, just address my comments above.

Comment: yes am using php. by "Invalid expression", i mean its the browser output upon the echo statement. i dont care if the error's from the xpath engine, as long as other valid xpressions didnt display dat. like i said, i want my output to update node DEEP (and possibly deeper nodes) from value attribute to any other value of my choice. i.e, xpected output should reflect on this line : <subsubchild DEEP = "Attribute"></subsubchild>   to : <subsubchild DEEP = "my choice"></subsubchild> finally i dont need a for loop solution, strictly xpath  ...............thanks

Comment: @OsagieOdigie, your question is confusing, and your responses in comments are not helping.  Mathias is very "knowledgable about wat's on ground" (for any reasonable interpretation of that bizarre construct), and JLRishe's answer is right on the mark.  I'm voting to close as unclear what you're asking until you improve your question:  Clear examples can overcome any English fluency challenges you might have, and losing the text-speak would show some respect for your readers.  Thanks.

Comment: I agree with @kjhughes, if you can change "wanna" to "want to", "wat" to "what", "u" to "you" and "pls" to "please" (etc) it is much appreciated - in your posts and in your comments. Fluent English speakers do not demand perfection, nor academic levels of formality, but equally we don't want Stack Overflow to become a chatroom (or worse yet, resemble YouTube comments). Avoiding text speak is a step in the right direction, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath to select the `subsubchild` you are targeting in this case is:

```
$query = "//*[@ID=333]//*[@DEEP = 'Attribute']";
```

To select the attribute itself, you could use:

```
$query = "//*[@ID=333]//*/@DEEP[. = 'Attribute']";
```

Note that I used single quotes inside the string because you can't use double quotes inside a double-quoted string unless you escape them.

It should also be noted that the use of `*node()` all in one clump is not valid in an XPath expression.

Comment: thanks @Rishe. but in actual sense, i dont know the node "subsubchild" at compile time (or test time if you dont mind). thats's why i used the xpath's node() function. how else can i obtain the node name at run time ? again, i actually wanna do a select all stuff, as in "//*[@ID=333]//*(unknown node)... to fetch any avilable match. thanks in advance.

Comment: @OsagieOdigie In the case that the element's name is unknown, you can use `*`. Please see my edit above.

Comment: am sorry for disturbing you. the function above (my new edit) shows what am trying to simulate. i've tried wat u said but still getting invalid expression. what did u see as d error ? thnks

Comment: @OsagieOdigie You're missing the quotes around `$attribValue`: `"//*[@ID=$ParentID]//*[@$attirbName = '$attribValue']"`

Comment: @Rishe thanks. but that's impossible as its not a string literal but a variable.

Comment: @OsagieOdigie How is it impossible to add two apostrophes to your code? I know full well that `$attribValue` is a variable, but you will have invalid XPath without those apostrophes.

Comment: Can you do an `echo $query` with that attempt in place and tell me what you see?

Comment: here's it : //*[@ID=333]//*[@DEEP= = Attribute]

Comment: @OsagieOdigie You have two `=`s when there should be only one, and it still doesn't have the two `'`s that I told you to add. Please use this string that I gave you two hours ago: `"//*[@ID=$ParentID]//*[@$attirbName = '$attribValue']"`. Don't tell me it doesn't work if you haven't tried it.

Comment: @Rishe honestly i've tried it. times without numbers. its getting me fraustrated. even now as you've commanded. still error

Comment: @OsagieOdigie Where is the `echo $query` output that you get when you use that exact string? Please show it to me.

Comment: it's here  again : //*[@ID=333]//*[@DEEP== 'Attribute']

Comment: funny enough i didnt include two == in the main query. but the output shows it

Comment: @OsagieOdigie Please do `echo $attirbName` and see whether that has an `=` in it.

Comment: @OsagieOdigie Well, that explains the problem. Do you know why $attirbName has a = in it?

Comment: no sir ! pls tell me if u knw. am sorry i slept off on top of the bug

Comment: @OsagieOdigie I certainly don't know. Where is `$attirbName` coming from? Where does it get its value?

Comment: hahahahahahahahaha a million thanks @JRishe. i've found the bug. the = was mistakenly passed as an argument to the XMLChangeAttribValue() method. i.e instead of : XMLChangeAttribValue(333, "DEEP", "Attribute", "blablabla"); i gave it : XMLChangeAttribValue(333, "DEEP=", "Attribute", "blablabla"); am glad its ok now. thanks man. i'll vote for you as the world bank president. hahahahahah